# Horizontal scroll for a div which contains other div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a 3 divs in a single row

Left and Right divs contains a single image of size 35px.
Middle div contains many other divs with a horizontal scroll

Left(35px) middle(not a fixed width, with horizontal scroll) right(35px)

Here is the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/zddm6asz/5/

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div>
 left
 <div>

 <div>
   <div> .... </div>
   <div> .... </div>
   <div> .... </div>
   ....
 </div>

 <div>
 Right
 </div>

</div>
```

I tried so much but still unable to do this. 
Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT**

This is not responsive design.
Middle div should occupy remain space in the row.

Left and right div are always at fixed width. In this case both are set to 35px;

Comment: Try to add ```position: absolute``` to ```wrapper``` class.

Comment: Not clear with your question. Do you want this to make responsive or to work  fixed width wrapper. What will happen when the middle DIV has lesser content. Does the right DIV comes closer or it stay on the right itself all the time

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using **floats**, you need to **set a width** to make them work.

```
.middle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%; /* Width is important for floats. */
  float: left;
  overflow: scroll; /* Allow scroll */
  white-space: nowrap; /* This will create the magic for the horizontal scroll */
}

.middleInner{
  display: inline-block; /* No float needed for inner elements */ 
}
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/z4teqy6s/1/)

Comment: Cool! I'm glad it helped @AbhijithNagaraja :)